# Is it possible to transform this function to use variadic parameters?

Tags: c++, qt

this sample uses Qt types/classes, but the topic is just about C++.

I have this function:

```
#define MAXIMUM_SUCCESSIVE_ERRORS 5

using TestExecFunc=std::function<bool(QString &)>;

bool MainWindow::testExec(TestExecFunc tefFunc,
                          QString      sTestName,
                          QString      &sError) {
    bool    bResult=false;
    int     iErrorCounter=0;
    while(true)
        if(tefFunc(sError)) {
            bResult=true;
            break;
        }
        else
            if(MAXIMUM_SUCCESSIVE_ERRORS<++iErrorCounter) {
                sError=QStringLiteral("%1 failed:\n%2").arg(sTestName,sError);
                int iSelection=QMessageBox::critical(
                    this,
                    QStringLiteral("Error"),
                    sError,
                    QMessageBox::Abort|QMessageBox::Retry,
                    QMessageBox::Retry
                );
                sError.remove(QStringLiteral("\n"));
                if(QMessageBox::Retry==iSelection)
                    iErrorCounter=0;
                else
                    break;
            }
    return bResult;
}
```

In a nutshell, what it does is, calling tefFunc(), if it fails, retries it, an after a given number of retries, asks the user to either keeps retrying or cancel the operation.

The second parameter, sTestName, is just a string to identify what's being tested.

The third parameter, &sError, is the error reason, returned by tefFunc() itself.

I am using testExec() like this:

```
QString sError;

if(this->testExec(
    [=](QString &sErr) {
        return(logout(sSession,sErr));
    },
    QStringLiteral("logout()"),
    sError
))
    qDebug() << "Logged out";
else
    qDebug() << sError;
```

That works flawlessly.

In the previous sample, logout() is declared like this:

```
static bool logout(const QString,QString &);
```

*There are a bunch of similar functions with the same structure*. I.e., returning a boolean, requiring a session string and another string where to store the possible error.

BUT with a different number of parameters **in the middle**. For example:

```
static bool getPageTags(const QString,int,QStringList &,QString &);
```

So to be able to use getPageTags() with testExec(), I'd do something like this:

```
int         iPage=1;
QString     sError;
QStringList slTags;

if(this->testExec(
    [&](QString &sErr) {
        return(getPageTags(sSession,iPage,slTags,sErr));
    },
    QStringLiteral("getPageTags(%1)").arg(iPage),
    sError
))
    qDebug() << "Page tags" << slTags;
else
    qDebug() << sError;
```

Now, my question is:

Is it possible to avoid the use of lambdas and directly call testExec() with each function and its parameter lists? For example:

```
if(this->testExec(
    logout,
    sSession,
    QStringLiteral("logout()"),
    sError
)) //...

if(this->testExec(
    getPageTags,
    sSession,
    iPage,
    slTags,
    QStringLiteral("getPageTags(%1)").arg(iPage),
    sError
)) // ...
```

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variadic pack as parameters can only be deduced as last parameter. Then you might have:

```
template <typename F, typename...Args>
bool MainWindow::testExec(QString      sTestName,
                          QString      &sError,
                          F tefFunc,
                          Args&&... args)
requires (requires { { tefFunc(args..., sError)} -> std::convertible_to<bool>;})
{
    int iErrorCounter = 0;

    while (true) {
        if (tefFunc(args..., sError)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if (MAXIMUM_SUCCESSIVE_ERRORS < ++iErrorCounter) {
                sError = QStringLiteral("%1 failed:\n%2").arg(sTestName, sError);
                int iSelection = QMessageBox::critical(
                    this,
                    QStringLiteral("Error"),
                    sError,
                    QMessageBox::Abort|QMessageBox::Retry,
                    QMessageBox::Retry
                );
                sError.remove(QStringLiteral("\n"));
                if (QMessageBox::Retry == iSelection)
                    iErrorCounter = 0;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get rid of `std::function`.

Comment: Well, that worked even without the `requires` part, which is good because I don't have a C++20 compiler.
I also got rid of the redundant &sError parameter (since it was already in the tefFunc parameters list) by using std::get() and std::tie().
The only drawback of this is that I cannot pass constants but I guess the solution (if exists) would be overly complicated. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: [`std::forward_as_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple) might help instead of `std::tie`.

Comment: My fault. I was using `Args&... args` instead of `Args&&... args`. Now with this one no `std::forward` is required and I can just call `if(tefFunc(args...))`, and get a reference (inside `testExec()`) to the last parameter (to wrap text around it) with `QString &sError=std::get<sizeof...(args)-1>(std::tie(args...))`.